# What is Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I was going through the Azure portal and completed most of its offered services like app service, VM, Storage etc. Now when I am reading questions about it I got to know one another service 'Azure Cloud Services'. I am now a little confused as I didn't find it on portal. I want to know does it exists now and if yes where can I find it in Azure portal.

Comment: It's one of the Azure Classic offering. It has been retired and replaced with Service Fabric.

Comment: Thank you so much @hendryanw but I have a doubt. I am reading an article 'https://mindmajix.com/azure-interview-questions'  and this is updated on 24 april, 2018. This article never mentioned it as a old service. So do you mean that I should not believe in this article and treat it as a lagacy part of Azure.

Comment: @hendryanw Cloud Service is not retired. It is very much alive and kicking though Microsoft is not encouraging the use of them. For new applications, recommendation is to use other PaaS offerings instead of Cloud Services.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks for correcting me. Yes that’s what I mean, I choose a wrong word.

Answer (score 8):

`Azure Cloud Service` (read `Web/Worker Roles`) is one of the earliest `Platform as a Service (PaaS)` offered by Microsoft Azure. In fact, when Azure started in 2008, Cloud Services was the only `Compute` option available in Azure (Virtual Machines, Websites etc. came a bit later).

With `Cloud Services` you can run web applications (typically by hosting your application in a Web Role) or run background applications (typically by hosting your application/background service in a Worker Role). Since it is a PaaS offering, you need not worry about the issues that comes with IaaS (i.e. patching, configuring etc.). You simply provide your application and the desired settings in form of a package to Microsoft and based on that Azure will create VMs for you and deploy your applications in those VMs.

Cloud Services offer you a lot of flexibility (when compared with WebApps), yet take away the complexities that you would normally face when working with Virtual Machines (IaaS).

Though not officially deprecated, Cloud Services is heading that way. Microsoft is pushing for the use of other PaaS offerings (like WebApps, WebJobs, Functions, Service Fabric etc.). If you're building a new app, my recommendation would be not to use Cloud Services.

Comment: Ok, So what I understood that it is available from classic azure and removed from Azure portal. Am I correct?

Comment: Fwiw, Cloud Services (classic) has is now officially deprecated and will be going away around August, 2024. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cloud-services-retirement-announcement/ for more information.

Answer (score -1):

sorry,
after i read the document
the answer is 
Azure Cloud Services = Azure Web App Services

it without creating vm,and deploy a web app (like .net web)

you can create it like picture:
[image]

and it's type is app service
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but as I was reading the document by Microsoft "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me", this tells something else and take 1. App service, 2. cloud service and 3 VM as 3 different entities. This confuse me.

Comment: Thanks for the correction but this not seems to be cloud service too as cloud service has roles like web roles and worker roles. I am not able to find these roles in App service or web apps. Also it is written that it is a PaaS service but host the VM instances. And here my question is really based on. I hope you got my question.

Comment: `Azure Cloud Services = Azure Web App Services` - This is incorrect! `Azure Cloud Service` is another `PaaS` service offered by Microsoft Azure like Azure WebApps.